# Sending a simple POST request from a controller symfony2 without cUrl

Tags: symfony, post, controller, request

I think there is a quite easy answer but, I tried to send a POST request to a REST api from a controller like that :

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

...

$request = Request::create('127.0.0.1', 'POST', array('test' => 'this is a test'));

but It did nothing, is there anything missing like send or execute method ?
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By doing so, you're only creating `Request` object. No actual request will be sent out.

To do that I suggest you use: [Buzz](https://github.com/kriswallsmith/buzz)

Ultimately, you may use [SensioBuzzBundle](https://github.com/sensiolabs/SensioBuzzBundle) in order to have `Buzz` as service

### EDIT:

Forgot to mention: I believe that `buzz` actually uses `curl`